# How to send a response on the site by Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, response, urllib

I need to send the response to the captcha to the site https://www.list-org.com/bot.

Here's html code of POST-request:

```
<form name="frm" method="POST">Вы слишком часто обращались к сайту и мы хотим убедиться, что вы не робот.<br>Повторите текст на картинке и сможете дальше работать:<br><br><img src="/kcap.php?PHPSESSID=iahvgmjcb93a0k7fqrf43sq9sk"><br><br><input type="text" name="keystring" autofocus=""><br><br><input type="submit" value=" Проверить! " name="submit"></form>enter code here
```

This is the part of the code that characterizes the response input field:

```
<input type="text" name="keystring" autofocus="">
```

This is the part of the code that characterizes the button:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Проверить! " name="submit">
```

How can I use urllib or request libraries to fill in the response field and click on the button?

P.S. I can translate Russian messages if necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to send POST request to the site:

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.list-org.com/bot'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0'}

data = {
    'keystring': 'xxx', # <--- put your string here
    'submit': '+Проверить!+'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    # load PHPSESSID cookie:
    s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    print(r.text)   # print response
```

Comment: Can you please describe the part where you make the request?

Comment: @Tohak `s.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)`  this will make a POST request with data in `data` dictionary.

Comment: So when I send a .post() response, I'm responding to a captcha? How do I know that I have completed it?

Comment: @Tohak after `r = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)` you can check response stored in `r` (text and/or url etc.)

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the requests module, which offers an easy to use and pleasant API for making web requests.

If you wish to imitate your web browser, I'd recommend making the requests with the network tab of your browsers developer console open. From there, find the request in the list, right click it, and choose copy -> copy as cURL.

From there, you will have the necessary cURL command to imitate the request. However, there is a utility that will convert the cURL command into request's code: https://curl.trillworks.com/

This tool will output the necessary code to issue the request using the Python requests library.

Comment: No, I don't need to simulate a web browser, just send an automatic response to the captcha and click. Is there any way to do this using only Python methods?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear here. It's not simulating a web browser in the way that Selenium would -- it's just imitating it in the sense that it will send the same user agent string and headers as your web browser would. Requests is pure python, it's just a library that's installable via `pip`.